# How to add a break in X axis?

Tags: r

I was wondering whether it is possible to make a plot in R with x axis containing one of the shapes below indicating that x axis is not starting from zero?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can be done. However, most authors of graphics packages believe that such axis breaks are bad practice and therefore didn't implement this. But a basic google search will yield some useful examples.

Comment: I have searched a lot but I could not find such a thing, would it be possible to mention a site or two please?

Comment: Well if I google 'R axis breaks' I get some useful results.

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("{axis break}")`

Answer (score 3):

How about the `axis.break()` from the package `plotrix`? For example:

```
library(plotrix)
plot(3:10,main="Axis break test")
# put a break at the default axis and position
axis.break()
# or at a certain position
axis.break(axis=1, breakpos=3) # on x-axis position 3
```

Comment: And I agree with Roland that this is not a very good practise, but it can be done.